# How to reassign the value in angular2 component getting undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services, ng2-charts, angular4-httpclient

I have a component  here declare the  numbers array  `public numbers :number[] =[];` and given the value for the numbers array in service response and getting 10 and after the ngInit block it shows as undefined

app.component.ts

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {  

      public numbers :number[] =[];  // here declare the variable
      public numberss :Iproduct[]

       ngOnInit(){ 
    // here call the service 

     this._productService.getproducts().subscribe((response) => {this.numberss = response;

    this.errornumber = 10;  // here ressign the value

    }
 }),(err)=> {this.errorMsg =<any>err};

       } // end of ngInit

// here is the 3rd party chart js  pass the this.errornumber gets undefined

    public doughnutChartOptions: any = {
      elements: {
        center: {
          text:this.errornumber +"% <br>products" ,
        }
      }
    };

    } // end of component
```

Here it is undefined why:`text:this.errornumber`

Answer (score 1):

Beacuse at the moment when doughnutChartOptions is defined this.errornumber not exist yet so it is undefined. After products are return by service then it is created and initialized. So, you should move creating doughnutChartOptions field to subscribe.

```
Example
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/CSXxSoWhxppw9ran4AcM?p=preview